# getting errors while importing openCV example for image stiching panorama example in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I am stuck at importing openCV example in eclipse on windows 7 from this link http://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/12/21/panorama-app-on-android-using-stitching-module-opencv/ 
 I have given path for my ndk folder in eclipse as well but I am getting these errors

> 16:11:25 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Tutorial 3 - Add Native OpenCV ****
>   "C:\Users\USer\AppData\Local\Android\NDKROOT\ndk-build.cmd" 
>   Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-21 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 9 in ./AndroidManifest.xml
>   jni/Android.mk:5: /sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk: No such file or directory
>   make.exe: *** No rule to make target `/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk'.  Stop.

following is my code where I am getting openCV errors
    package org.opencv.samples.tutorial3;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Sample3Native extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener {
private static final String TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";

public static final int VIEW_MODE_RGBA = 0;
public static final int SAVE_IMAGE_MAT = 1;
 public static final int CAPT_STILL_IM = 2;
private static int viewMode = VIEW_MODE_RGBA;
//  public static int image_count = 0;
private MenuItem mStitch;
private MenuItem mItemCaptureImage;
private Mat mRgba;
private Mat mGrayMat;
private Mat panorama;
private Mat mtemp;
private List<Mat> images_to_be_stitched = new ArrayList<Mat>();
private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
private long mPrevTime = new Date().getTime();
private static final int FRAME2GRAB = 10;
private int mframeNum = 0;
private static final File tempImageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "panoTmpImage");
private static final File StitchImageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator  + "panoStitchIm");
private static final String mImageName = "im";
private static final String mImageExt = ".jpeg";
private long recordStart = new Date().getTime();
private static final long MAX_VIDEO_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 3 * 1000; // Convert milliseconds to seconds
public final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

// Create runnable for posting
final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        updateResultsInUi();
    }
};

private void updateResultsInUi()
{

}

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
        case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
            Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

            // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
            System.loadLibrary("native_sample");

            mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
        }
            break;
        default: {
            super.onManagerConnected(status);
        }
            break;
        }
    }
};

public Sample3Native() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial3_surface_view);


    final Button btnVidCapt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVidCapt);
    btnVidCapt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startVidCap();
        }
    });

    final Button btnStitch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStitch);
    btnStitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stitchImages();
        }
    });

    final Button btnViewStitchedIm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewStitchedIm);
    btnViewStitchedIm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewStitchImages();
        }
    });

    final Button btnCapStil = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapStil);
    btnCapStil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            captStillImage();
        }
    });
    mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial4_activity_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this,
            mLoaderCallback);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
    mGrayMat = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    mtemp = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
    panorama = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
}

public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mRgba.release();
    mGrayMat.release();
    mtemp.release();
    panorama.release();
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) {
    inputFrame.copyTo(mRgba);
    switch (Sample3Native.viewMode) {
    case Sample3Native.VIEW_MODE_RGBA: {
        Core.putText(mRgba, "Video Mode", new Point(10, 50), 3, 1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 2);
        // Update start recordtime until starting recording
    }break;
    case Sample3Native.SAVE_IMAGE_MAT: {
        long curTime = new Date().getTime();
        Core.putText(mRgba, "Record Mode", new Point(10, 50), 3, 1, new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 2);
        long timeDiff = curTime - recordStart;
        Log.i("timeDiff", Long.toString(timeDiff));

        if ( timeDiff < MAX_VIDEO_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS) {
            if ((mframeNum % FRAME2GRAB) == 0) {
                saveImageToArray(inputFrame);
                mframeNum++;
            } 
            else
                mframeNum++;
        } 
        else
        {
            mframeNum = 0;
            turnOffCapture();
        }
    }break;
    case Sample3Native.CAPT_STILL_IM :
    {
        saveImageToArray(inputFrame);
        Sample3Native.viewMode = Sample3Native.VIEW_MODE_RGBA;
    }
    }
    return mRgba;
}

public void startVidCap() {
    if (Sample3Native.viewMode == Sample3Native.VIEW_MODE_RGBA)
    {
        turnOnCapture();
    }
    else if (Sample3Native.viewMode == Sample3Native.SAVE_IMAGE_MAT)
    {
        turnOffCapture();
    }
}

private void turnOffCapture()
{   
//      Button startVidCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVidCapt);
    // Stop Recording
//      startVidCapture.setText("Start Video Capture");
    Sample3Native.viewMode = Sample3Native.VIEW_MODE_RGBA; 
}
private void turnOnCapture()
{
//      Button startVidCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVidCapt);
    // Start recording
    Sample3Native.viewMode = Sample3Native.SAVE_IMAGE_MAT; 
//      startVidCapture.setText("Stop Video Capture");
    images_to_be_stitched.clear();
    recordStart = new Date().getTime();

}

public void stitchImages() {
    if(!images_to_be_stitched.isEmpty())
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < images_to_be_stitched.size(); j++) {
            writeImage(images_to_be_stitched.get(j), j);
        }
    Log.i("stitchImages", "Done writing 2 disk. Starting stitching " +        images_to_be_stitched.size() + " images");
        FindFeatures(images_to_be_stitched.get(0).getNativeObjAddr(),
                images_to_be_stitched.get(0).getNativeObjAddr(),
                panorama.getNativeObjAddr(), images_to_be_stitched.size());
    Log.i("stitchImages", "Done stitching. Writing panarama");
        writePano(panorama);

    Log.i("stitchImages", "deleting temp files");

        deleteTmpIm();
    }
}

public void captStillImage()
{
    Sample3Native.viewMode = Sample3Native.CAPT_STILL_IM;

}

private String getFullFileName( int num)
{
    return mImageName + num + mImageExt;
}

/*  private void writeImage(List<Mat> imList) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (Mat im : imList) {
        String fileName = "/sdcard/im" + counter + ".jpeg";
//          Highgui.imwrite(s, images_to_be_stitched.get(j));
        counter++;
    }
}
*/  
private void writeImage(Mat image, int imNum)
{
    writeImage(image, getFullFileName(imNum));
}

private void writeImage(Mat image, String fileName) {
    File createDir = tempImageDir;
    if(!createDir.exists())
        createDir.mkdir();
    Highgui.imwrite(tempImageDir+File.separator + fileName, image);
}


private void writePano(Mat image)
{
    Date dateNow = new  Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
    if(!StitchImageDir.exists())
        StitchImageDir.mkdir();
    Highgui.imwrite(StitchImageDir.getPath()+ File.separator + "panoStich"+dateFormat.format(dateNow) +mImageExt, image);

}

private void deleteTmpIm()
{
    File curFile;
    for (int j = 0; j < images_to_be_stitched.size(); j++) {
        curFile = new File(getFullFileName(j));
        curFile.delete();
    }
    images_to_be_stitched.clear();
}


public void viewStitchImages() 
{
//      Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
//      photoPickerIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//      photoPickerIntent.setData(Uri.parse(StitchImageDir         +File.separator+"*");
//      startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
/*      Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    photoPickerIntent.setType(StitchImageDir +File.separator+"*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(photoPickerIntent,"Select   Picture"), 1);
*/      
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GalleryActivity.class);
//      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content:"    + StitchImageDir.getAbsolutePath()));//media/external/images/media"));
//      EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
//      String message = editText.getText().toString();
//      intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void saveImageToArray(Mat inputFrame) {
    images_to_be_stitched.add(inputFrame.clone());
}

private int FPS() {
    long curTime = new Date().getTime();
    int FPS = (int) (1000 / (curTime - mPrevTime));
    mPrevTime = curTime;
    return FPS;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
/*      Log.i(TAG, "called onCreateOptionsMenu");
    mStitch = menu.add("Stitch Images");
    mItemCaptureImage = menu.add("Capture Image");
*/      return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
/*      Log.i(TAG, "called onOptionsItemSelected; selected item: " + item);

    if (item == mItemCaptureImage) {
           mOpenCvCameraView.SetCaptureFormat(Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA);
        viewMode = SAVE_IMAGE_MAT;
    } else if (item == mStitch) {
        mOpenCvCameraView.SetCaptureFormat(Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_COLOR_FRAME_RGBA);
        viewMode = VIEW_STITCH;
    }
*/      return true;
}

// public native void FindFeatures(List<Long> pano_images, Long stitch );
public native void FindFeatures(long image1, long image2, long image3,
        int count);
}
```

my ndk path is this

> C:\Users\USer\AppData\Local\Android\NDKROOT

can anyone help me to correctly configure openCV in my sample panorama project ?